# How can I "validate" CWnd* object?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

(There's a TL;DR on the last line)

I'm implementing a handler to close selected windows open in a software application. Here's a rough code:

```
void CDlg_Dummy_Dialog::OnCloseWindows()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_WindowsInfo.size(); i++) {
        Window_Node *pWN = &m_WindowsInfo.at(i);
        if (pWN->checked && IsWindow(pWN->pWnd->GetSafeHwnd())) {
            pWN->pWnd->GetParentFrame()->SendMessage(WM_CLOSE);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are some declarations of the parameters shown above:

```
struct Window_Node {
    CString name;
    CString path;
    CWnd *pWnd;
    BOOL checked;
    HICON icon;
    ....
};

class CDlg_Dummy_Dialog : public CDialog {
    ...
protected:
    std::vector<struct Window_Node> m_WindowsInfo;
    ...
}
```

Also, there can be multiple instances of `Window_Node` with different `pWnd` parameter, originating from a single `CDocument` class (ie. different types of windows exist to show different displays for the document).

[image]

For this software, if the first window of the document (which is always the "green" Window type in the diagram) is closed, all other windows associated with that document will automatically be closed with them. This is where the problem happens.

If the user selects multiple windows from the same document (with the green window among them), it closes all windows by the time it finishes the first iteration, and all `pWnd` pointers are now pointing to a now unassigned memory. Therefore, when it tries to call `GetSafeHwnd()` on the next iteration, it prompts a memorry access violation error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x00000000521B4AD0 (mfc100d.dll) in Settle3D.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000136943E0.
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000521B4AD0 (mfc100d.dll) in Settle3D.exe: 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback.
```

I'm aware that the easy fix would be to iterate through the vector in the opposite direction. However, I am trying to integrate this method on several other software as well, and they don't necessarily organize their windows in the same manner.

So, after all the long question above, here's TL;DR:

**Is there any way to check if an instance of CWnd* is pointing to a valid window?**

Comment: Using a deallocated object is undefined behavior. There is no way to recover from that. You *need* a strategy that never accesses deallocated objects.

Comment: Pointers can point to anywhere:  valid locations and invalid locations (no memory at the address, etc).  The harder validation comes when the pointer is pointing within a valid area of memory.  Without better data, there is no telling if a pointer is pointing to a valid object, a wrong object of the same type or an object of an incompatible type.

Comment: `if (pWN->checked && IsWindow(pWN->pWnd->GetSafeHwnd()))` you are not checking if `pWN` is non-NULL, same with `pWN->pWnd` Also you can get direct access to frame window via `AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd`

Comment: You need to fix your error. Your specific error is: Storing redundant information. If it weren't redundant, you wouldn't run into a situation, where you are unsure whether or not a pointer is valid. And there is absolutely no way at all to verify, whether a pointer points to an object of a particular type.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: I've gotten rid of them, because dereferencing either of those doesn't necessarily return NULL even if the pointer is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to start with your main window, and recursively search through the child windows if you find the HWND in question.

Get the first child with `CWnd::GetWindow(GW_CHILD)` and the next windows with `CWnd::GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT)`.